# UPS or Stabilizer for LED TV

Tags: television

Just bought a Panasonic LED TV. I want to protect it from voltage fluctuation and power interruption as in my area power goes frequently and my society has power back once power goes, generator on and power comes in 10-15 sec. Should I buy a stabilizer or UPS to protect my TV? I already lost my SONY TV because of power interruption.

Need your expert advice.

Comment: Does this TV have a 12 volt input, by chance?  Many do.

Answer (score 2):

To cover a 15-second outage (power interruption) you need a UPS.

A basic UPS should protect your TV from surges, brownouts and overvoltages by switching to battery power (with a very short interruption to power) but during an extended brownout/overvoltage it will eventually cut power to the TV.

To cover extended brownouts or overvoltages, you need a [line-interactive UPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply#Line-interactive).

Comment: I agree ups is the only way to go and will protect it form generator fluctuations.+

Comment: UPS's are picky about power quality, and many will stay on battery all the time when on a small generator with poor power quality (either bad frequency stabilization, or a bad sinewave approximation). For a larger 20KVA+ generator, this is less of a problem. I used to run a site on generator, and we couldn't get the UPS's to run consistently on small generators (even quality inverter based 4KVA and 6KVA generators) until we brought in the big trailer mounted diesel generator.

Comment: @Johnny: presumably an online/double-conversion UPS would cope with that? Though cost may make alternative approaches better.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - That's what we thought too, we tried several double conversion UPS's (Eaton, APC, Triplite) and though they were a little better than the line interactive UPS's, they still didn't like the power quality we were getting from the smaller generators and they spent so much time on battery that the batteries would drain. The only effective solution we found was to use a larger, more stable generator.